# Can I use a javascript variable to query Neo4j?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, neo4j

I am wondering if it is possible to use a local userInput variable, to modify queries. I.e. the name that the user gives through this input form:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
```

Like this:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
        statements: [{
            statement:'MATCH (tom {name: "userInput"}) RETURN tom' //'MATCH (n) RETURN n'

        }]
    });
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
type: "POST",
data: body,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json"

})

      .done(function(result){
        console.log(result.results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Grab the text input by id and access the value like this:

```
document.getElementById('userInput').value
```

Comment: You need to provide more info than that for me to be able to help you. What part isn't working? If I put your text input on my page, type a value into it and use the code I provided above in the console, I get the value back. If you are replacing "userInput" with your value then you'll need to concatenate it like this: 'MATCH (tom {name: "' + document.getElementById('userInput').value + '"}) return tom' (although once you get it working you'll want to sanitize the user input). Please provide more specifics.